# Is there any specific name for this inequality: $\langle x, y \rangle \leq \frac{\| x\|_2^2 + \| y\|_2^2 }{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> Is there any specific name for this inequality:
>
> $$\langle x, y \rangle \leq \frac{\| x\|_2^2 + \| y\|_2^2 }{2}$$

Comment: It's just cauchy schwarz and AM-GM inequality which gives you $\langle x,y \rangle \le ||x|||y|| \le \frac{||x||^2 + ||y||^2}{2}$

Comment: It could also be Cauchy-Schwarz-Young inequality.

Comment: If one write this as $\sum x_i^2 + \sum y_i^2 \ge 2 \sum x_i y_i$, it is just a sum of $n$ AM-GM inequalities. (where the dimension of $x$ is $n$.)

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you so much.

Comment: @VictorHugo Thank you

Comment: @dust05 Thank you

Comment: @DominikKutek It's simpler than that:
$$
0 \leqslant \|x - y\|^2 = \left\langle x - y, x - y \right\rangle =
\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 - 2\left\langle x, y \right\rangle.
$$