# How to upper bound this $\langle x, Ay \rangle \leq {\rm ?} $ in terms of the sum of norms of $x$ and $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

I am interested in bounding this 
$$\langle x, Ay \rangle \leq {\rm ?} $$ in terms of the sums of norms of $x$ and  $y$ ([special case where matrix $A$ can be seen as an identity matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686469/is-there-any-specific-name-for-this-inequality-langle-x-y-rangle-leq-frac?noredirect=1#comment7576792_3686469))?

---

Partial attempt

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, then I am not sure
\begin{align}
\langle x, Ay \rangle 
&\leq \|x \|_2 \|A\|_2 \|y\|_2 \\
&\overset{?}{\leq} \left( \|x \|_2^2 + \|A\|_2^2 + \|y\|_2^2 \right),
\end{align}
where $\|A\|_2$ is a [spectral norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases).

---

**Attempt2** (Considering Jean Marie's answer and comment)

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, then applying AM-GM on the norms of $\| x\|$ and $\| y\|$, that is,

\begin{align}
\langle x, Ay \rangle 
&\leq \|x \|_2 \|A\|_2 \|y\|_2 \\
&\leq \frac{\|A\|_2}{2} \left( \|x \|_2^2 + \|y\|_2^2 \right).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an important **lack of homogeneity** drawback to attempt such inequations with additions :

\begin{align}
\langle x, Ay \rangle 
&\overset{?}{\leq} \left( a\|x \|_2^2 + b\|A\|_2^2 + c\|y\|_2^2 \right),
\end{align}

(I have added coefficients $a,b,c$ to make the RHS even more general).

I mean by "lack of homogeneity" the fact that for example,

- if you replace $x$ by $\lambda x$ and $y$ by $\frac{1}{\lambda} y$, the LHS is unchanged, whereas the RHS is changed, becoming an expression of the form

$$u+v \lambda^2 +\dfrac{w}{\lambda^2}$$

that will be difficult to manage for example because it can be made arbitrarily large.

- if you replace $x$ by $\lambda x$, $y$ by $\lambda y$, $A$ by $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}A$, the LHS is unchanged, whereas the RHS becomes an expression of the form

$$u\lambda^4 +\dfrac{v}{\lambda^4}$$

etc...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I see your point. How about this approach and ignore the summation of spectral norm of $A$. $\langle x, Ay \rangle 
\leq \|x \|_2 \|A\|_2 \|y\|_2 \leq  \frac{\|A\|_2}{2}  \left( \| x \|_2^2 + \| y \|_2^2 \right)$?

Comment: I think it's much more "harmonious", with a coefficient $\frac12$ that could be something else ($\alpha$) ;  In particular, grouping everything in the RHS and writing it under a "canonical" form $ a'\(|x \|_2 + b  \|y\|_2)^2 +c \ge 0 $ will be informative about the good $\alpha$ to be chosen ...

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

As Jean Marie has already pointed out, finding an upper bound purely in terms of sums of $\|x\|$, $\|y\|$ and $\|A\|$ seems rather difficult.

What you could try however is [polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity)
$$\langle x, Ay \rangle = \frac{1}{4}\left(\|x + Ay \|^2 - \|x - Ay\|^2\right) \leq \frac{1}{4}\|x + Ay\|^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}\left(\|x\| + \|Ay\|\right)^2.$$